# How to retrun value 1 or 2 or both conditons SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, where-clause

In a stored procedure have a table variable called, `@detaiResultTable` and, This is my part of stored procedure and how I inserting data into that table variable.

```
INSERT INTO @detaiTable 
SELECT b.branchid, 
       sp.fkserviceid, 
       Count(sp.fkserviceid) AS ServiceCount 
FROM   location l 
       INNER JOIN @Branches br 
               ON l.fkbranchid = br.branchid 
WHERE  l.addedlocaltime >= @startDate 
       AND sp.servicetime IS NOT NULL 
GROUP  BY b.branchid, 
          sp.fkserviceid
```

I need to check another flag called `@fkTypeID` and its value can be 1, 2 or 0

- When `@fkTypeID = 1` need to retrieve  `fkTypeID = 1` data
- When `@fkTypeID = 2` need to retrieve  `fkTypeID = 2` data
- When `@fkTypeID = 0` need to retrieve  `fkTypeID = 1 and 2` data

Newly introduced flag as follows,

```
INSERT INTO @detaiTable 
SELECT b.branchid, 
       sp.fkserviceid, 
       Count(sp.fkserviceid) AS ServiceCount 
FROM   location l 
       INNER JOIN @Branches br 
               ON l.fkbranchid = br.branchid 
WHERE  l.addedlocaltime >= @startDate and fkTypeID = @fkTypeID
and sp.ServiceTime is not null
GROUP  BY b.branchid, 
          sp.fkserviceid
```

What is the shortest way to do this, I'm plan to do this as this.

```
IF @fkTypeID = 0 
  BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO @detaiTable 
      SELECT b.branchid, 
             sp.fkserviceid, 
             Count(sp.fkserviceid) AS ServiceCount 
      FROM   location l 
             INNER JOIN @Branches br 
                     ON l.fkbranchid = br.branchid 
      WHERE  l.addedlocaltime >= @startDate 
             AND sp.servicetime IS NOT NULL 
      GROUP  BY b.branchid, 
                sp.fkserviceid 
  END 
ELSE 
  BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO @detaiTable 
      SELECT b.branchid, 
             sp.fkserviceid, 
             Count(sp.fkserviceid) AS ServiceCount 
      FROM   location l 
             INNER JOIN @Branches br 
                     ON l.fkbranchid = br.branchid 
      WHERE  l.addedlocaltime >= @startDate 
             AND fktypeid = @fkTypeID 
             AND sp.servicetime IS NOT NULL 
      GROUP  BY b.branchid, 
                sp.fkserviceid 
  END
```

but problem is, In my SP have multiple table variable like this. So if I write code this. it will make huge code in my SP. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to express the logic is:

```
where (@fkTypeID = fkTypeID or @fkTypeId = 0)
```

Note that in a stored procedure, this can affect the performance of the query if `fkTypeID` is used for an index or partition.  What happens is that the query gets compiled with the first value of the parameter -- and that might not be optimal for other values.

However, with only two values for the type id, this probably won't have much impact, though, so performance may not be affected.

Comment: @Sachith FYI the use of "Dude" here can be viewed as rather rude.